# How to change color of first element in a list box in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm a beginner in dev, and I'm trying to change the color of the first list element in an ngFor condition. Let me introduce you my issue with images.

By default I would like to have de 1st element in grey:
[List Box Grey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85KfA.jpg)

And the others element in blue when I select them. The 1st element should alwayse appear in grey and the other in blue. I would like to do that with CSS code. [List box open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rZab.png)

I looked for some solutions as:

```
select.mat-input-element:checked {
    color : blue;
  }

  select.mat-input-element:not(:checked) {
    color: grey;
  }

  select option:first-child {
   // color : grey;
  }

  select option:active {
    color : blue;
  }


  select option[value=Selection 1] {
    color :grey;
  }

  select option[value="Selection 1"] {
    color :grey;
  }
```

But nothing works... Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work , but i quess you'd be better off using a configurable dropdownlist with JS if you like to do more styling.

```css
        #test {
            color: #00c;
        }
        
        #test option {
            color: #c00;
        }
        
        #test option:first-of-type {
            color: #fc0;
        }
```

```html
 <body>
   <select id="test">
        <option value="1">
            first
        </option>
        <option value="2">second</option>
    </select>
 </body>
```